# Handling url based RBAC with Spring Security OAuth2 and Okta

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, okta, okta-api

I have setup application and authorization server on Okta. I have added two groups, namely `admin` and `users`. The authentication flow is working fine but when I try to print the roles, I am getting the output as below

`[SCOPE_address, SCOPE_phone, SCOPE_offline_access, SCOPE_openid, ROLE_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_profile]`

The Java code to print the roles is as below:

```
@RequestMapping("/securedPage")
    public String securedPage(Model model, Principal principal) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        Set<String> roles = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
             .map(r -> r.getAuthority()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
                System.out.println(roles);
         return roles.toString();
    }
```

application.properties

```
okta.oauth2.client-id=<client-id>
okta.oauth2.client-secret=<client-secret>
okta.oauth2.issuer=<issuer-url>
okta.oauth2.redirect-uri=/login
okta.oauth2.roles-claim=groups
server.port=9222
logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE
```

When I access the login page and enter the `username` and `password`, the roles are not getting displayed. But strangely I am seeing `ROLE_USER` but I have added the uses into `users` group.

I am following this guide `https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/10/13/okta-groups-spring-security`. I am not sure, how to configure the roles for authorization in Spring Security.

The below is the Spring Security Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityWebAppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


    @Bean  
    GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() { 
        return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults(""); // Remove the ROLE_ prefix  
    } 

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
uestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/securedPage'; against '/'
2021-01-09 00:41:57.674 DEBUG 21292 --- [nio-9222-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /securedPage; Attributes: [authenticated]
2021-01-09 00:41:57.678 DEBUG 21292 --- [nio-9222-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken@dffd3eb: Principal: Name: [00u3g2nr7ISCACRyk5d6], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_address, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_offline_access, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_phone, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=dHbIlPZ1tUzL-y5vmVb1cQ, sub=00u3g2nr7ISCACRyk5d6, zoneinfo=America/Los_Angeles, ver=1, email_verified=true, amr=["pwd"], iss=https://dev-9729512.okta.com/oauth2/edukart, preferred_username=kishore@gmail.com, locale=en-US, given_name=kishore, nonce=FxcHjdKHTsisyWG8jiLgEbH84H2AxyCdISv5U0JyVA8, aud=[0oa3eaj576gLDYwsh5d6], updated_at=2021-01-07T19:46:08Z, idp=00o3ct0plX9rgiTmB5d6, auth_time=2021-01-08T18:48:46Z, name=kishore kumar, exp=2021-01-08T20:11:54Z, family_name=kumar, iat=2021-01-08T19:11:54Z, email=kishore@gmail.com, jti=ID.xLH6W1loE_ELRLCWEuyGHV42-pkw3eCDqfNVlyQOfnc}]; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@43458: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: D028931C57C35976D9AB6FC2C9543B4B; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER, SCOPE_address, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_offline_access, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_phone, SCOPE_profile
```

Where am I going wrong and how to debug with Okta groups to Spring Security Roles.

**Update**:
I updated the `okta-spring-boot-starter` version to `1.4.0` and now I am able to see the `admins` role that was assigned to the user.
`roles :: [SCOPE_address, Everyone, SCOPE_phone, SCOPE_offline_access, SCOPE_openid, ROLE_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_profile, admins]`

**Questions**:

1. Why is the roles fetched only when configured the claims with  `ID-Token` in `include in token type` and not while sending it as part of `ACCESS_TOKEN` in Okta
2. I do not see an option to set the claims to both ID-TOKEN and ACCESS TOKEN in the claims tab. Its a drop down and I can choose only one.
3. Why is the granted authority showing it as `admins` and not as `ROLE_ADMINS`

```
Principal :: Name: [00u40teh2owUKq5ZL5d6], Granted Authorities: [[Everyone, ROLE_USER, SCOPE_address, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_offline_access, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_phone, SCOPE_profile, admins]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=uB-Gcqt-H6ezmv8KpIpx_g, sub=00u40teh2owUKq5ZL5d6, zoneinfo=America/Los_Angeles, ver=1, email_verified=true, amr=["pwd"], iss=https://dev-7858070.okta.com/oauth2/default, groups=["Everyone","admins"], preferred_username=ramesh@gmail.com, locale=en-US, given_name=ramesh, nonce=KXqGlhOj5ZVoChXo-ATjoHW-9ABAcEi5AnukAGXxg78, aud=[0oa3mz4mtisXjRJf85d6], updated_at=2021-01-20T03:17:42Z, idp=00o3myy20pqywuN5o5d6, auth_time=2021-01-21T03:02:46Z, name=ramesh kumar, exp=2021-01-21T04:02:49Z, family_name=kumar, iat=2021-01-21T03:02:49Z, email=ramesh@gmail.com, jti=ID.XQ4cKdIMuQKJv941EkYyDFJDCtKFAzaItPdyLPkMXPQ}] roles :: [SCOPE_address, Everyone, SCOPE_phone, SCOPE_offline_access, SCOPE_openid, ROLE_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_profile, admins]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the "Authorization Server" section in the blog post you mentioned:

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/10/13/okta-groups-spring-security#authorization-server

The post used an older version of these libraries, but make sure you have the "groups" claim defined.  You likely need to set the "include in token type" value to "both" (or follow the same steps to create one for the "ID Token" as well)

This post likely predated OIDC support in Spring Security.

Keep us posted, if that was the issue I'll tweak the post to mention that.

If that doesn't help, use the "Token Preview" tab on the "Authorization Server" configuration page in your Okta Admin/Developer Console.
You should see a "groups" claim listed, once everything is configured correctly.

Update (answering other questions):

1. ID Token vs Access Token claims
   This gets into the weeds a bit related to the OAuth 2.0 and OIDC specs. But the TL;DR is older versions of Spring Security used OAuth 2.0 and Access Tokens, newer versions can use OIDC and ID Tokens.

   There are other flows that would use Access Tokens too, for a more detailed description on the differences between the two and which flows use which tokens, checkout the Okta Dev [YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/oktadev)
2. This one was my fault, I miss remembered this page.
   You can just create the claim for both token types.
3. It uses the names that are in group, if you want it to use `ROLE_ADMIN` instead you can create an Okta group with that name.

Comment: I have followed the steps and I am able to see the groups claim listed using the "Token Preview" tab in the "Authorization server". But with the spring boot application I am still getting 403 error for all users. Is there an updated version of the Blog.

Comment: What request are you seeing a 403 on?

Comment: I am now able to fetch the roles after upgrading the `okta-spring-boot` version to `1.4.0`. However, there are still two open questions. Please see the update section of the original post.